# Showing a loading animation for an iframe in a jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

UI experts,
 I'm trying to get a slow website loaded in an iframe within a jquery modal dialog, but I'm having trouble. This is my use case:

1. open a jquery dialog, with a single "loading..." gif
2. load a different URL in the background
3. once loaded, replace the gif with the URL

I'm able to open the URL directly with code as below:

```
    var popup = $('<div id="popup123" class="dialog"></div>').prependTo('body');
    popup.prepend('<iframe style="display:none" class="dialogIFrame"></iframe>');
    $('.dialogIFrame').attr("src", 'http://myslowsite');
    $('.dialogIFrame').show();
    popup.dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Site',
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
    });
```

So my question is - how do I add a "loading..." gif to the mix? Should be possible - but I can't seem to figure out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this. Hope it helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/CEJhb/1/

```
var popup = $('<div id="popup123" class="dialog"><img id="load" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="loading..."/></div>').prependTo('body');

popup.prepend('<iframe style="display:none" class="dialogIFrame"></iframe>');
var $iFrame = $('iframe');

$iFrame.load(function() {
$('.dialogIFrame').show();
$('#load').hide();
});

$('.dialogIFrame').attr("src", 'http://www.google.com');

popup.dialog({
modal: true,
title: 'Site',
width: 1000,
height: 500
});​
```

Comment: This is much closer to what I want. I'm trying this.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of creating an iframe, directing it to a site and performing a callback when it finishes loading: http://jsfiddle.net/74nhr/109/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var status = $('#status');
    var iframe = $('iframe');

    status.val('Loading...'); // show wait

    iframe.on('load', function() {
        status.val('Done!');  // remove wait, done!
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.attr('src', 'http://www.archive.org');
    },
    1000);
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks Cymen. I doubt that works - since the iframe still has display:none - and I'm doing a .show after the .attr('src') - 3rd line. I tried it, and it doesn't display the loading gif. Maybe someone can post complete code? I admit I'm new to jquery UI.

Comment: You could of course just show the iframe with the loading HTML. Maybe you want some other functionality? Anyway, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Cymen - I want to show Loading.. in the iframe itself. I'm trying the above code. It seems I need to adapt to the jquery UI dialog case. Let me try...

Comment: Works on Jquery 1.7.x and upper. +1 To give this answer on my birthday :)